# Is the half-homomorphic property of RSA a problem for blind RSA signatures?

Tags: rsa, factoring, blind-signature, homomorphic-signatures

For blind RSA signatures, is it problematic that RSA is half-homomorph?

Take a scenario where blind RSA signatures are used for something like a voting procedure or [this proposal](https://zyan.scripts.mit.edu/blog/rate-limiting-anonymous-accounts/): Lots of people, potentially malicious, are given the ability to sign a limited amount of messages without revealing the content of the messages to the signing party.

The attack scenario I have in mind is as follows: The attacker lets the party with the private key blind-sign the primes in a factor base, then tries to create to-be-signed data that is smooth over the factor base, letting him make his own signatures by multiplying together the signatures he already knows.

Is that not a problem because so few numbers are smooth over a relatively small factor base?

Comment: As long as you use a good padding scheme (full-domain-hash is simple and strong) it shouldn't be possible to obtain more than one padded message for which you know the pre-image per signing query.